# How to use Python to get DST addresses out of a syslog file

Tags: python, parsing

So, I have a log file that my home router generates. It has hundreds of lines. And each line looks like this:  (long line below). I want to parse this file to get all the "DST" addresses. For example, from the line below, the DST address is "16.99.99.102"

```
Dec 10 16:02:02 ? user.warn kernel: DROP IN=br0 OUT=vlan1 SRC=192.168.1.127 DST=16.99.99.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=24724 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62694 DPT=443 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030201010402)
```

1. What is the best way to do this using Python?
   Eventually, I want to run these DST ip addresses through an iplookup query to get the domain names.
2. My ideal script would be to put the timestamp at the beginning, the SRC address and the DST address - all of these, separately, into a dictionary, whose keys are the "SRC" ip addresses, and whose corresponding value is a list that contains the DST address and the timestamp.

I am not necessarily looking for an elegant script, but something that works!

A solution to (1) is good enough, but a solution to (2) will be a bonus!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
In [30]: somestr = "Dec 10 16:02:02 ? user.warn kernel: DROP IN=br0 OUT=vlan1 SRC=192.168.1.127 DST=16.99.99.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=24724 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62694 DPT=443 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030201010402)"

In [31]: somestr.split()
Out[31]: 
['Dec',
 '10',
 '16:02:02',
 '?',
 'user.warn',
 'kernel:',
 'DROP',
 'IN=br0',
 'OUT=vlan1',
 'SRC=192.168.1.127',
 'DST=16.99.99.102',
 'LEN=52',
 'TOS=0x00',
 'PREC=0x00',
 'TTL=127',
 'ID=24724',
 'DF',
 'PROTO=TCP',
 'SPT=62694',
 'DPT=443',
 'WINDOW=8192',
 'RES=0x00',
 'SYN',
 'URGP=0',
 'OPT',
 '(020405B40103030201010402)']

In [32]: [i for i in somestr.split() if i.startswith("DST")][0].partition('=')[-1]
Out[32]: '16.99.99.102'
```

Answer (score 0):

For option A:
If all the lines are in the same format (and order) you can substring each line:

`dst = line[line.find("DST=")+len("DST="):line.find("LEN=")]`

For option B, you can follow the same idea, in the loop:

```
D = {}
for line in lines:
    dst = line[line.find("DST=")+len("DST="):line.find("LEN=")]
    src = line[line.find("SRC=")+len("SRC="):line.find("DST=")]
    ts = line[:line.find("?")]

    D[src] = (dst,ts)
```

You also may want to `strip()` the resulting strings for a cleaner result.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex for this

something like

```
>>> xxy = "Dec 10 16:02:02 ? user.warn kernel: DROP IN=br0 OUT=vlan1 SRC=192.168.1.127 DST=16.99.99.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=24724 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62694 DPT=443 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030201010402)"
>>> re.findall("^([^?]*).*DST=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)",xxy)
[('Dec 10 16:02:02 ', '16.99.99.102')]
```